# Solve $3^{x-1}\cdot2^{3x-7}<12^{9-x}$

Tags: inequality

I tried to solve this inequality many times tried different approaches but I can't seem to find the right way. I tried taking apart each one or to find something common so I could replace with a letter $u$ or $v$ but it doesn't work.

> $$3^{x-1}\cdot2^{3x-7}<12^{9-x}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3^{x-1}2^{3x-7}<12^{9-x}\\
3^{x-1}2^{3x-7}<3^{9-x}4^{9-x}\\
3^{x-1}2^{3x-7}<3^{9-x}2^{18-2x}$

What follows doesn't usually work.  But the numbers were nicely chosen such that:

$x-1 = 9 -x  \implies x = 5$ and $3x-7 = 18-2x \implies x = 5$

$x=5 \implies 3^{x-1}2^{3x-7}=12^{9-x}$

And since the left hand side increase as x increases and the right hand side decreases as x increases, we can say

$x<5$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\frac{3^x 2^{3x}}{12^{-x}} = (2^5 \cdot 3^2)^x$$

Comment: Could you please explain what happened to 12^9 and to 3^-1 2^-7

Comment: Put them together on the other side of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Take logarithm of both sides to get

$$(x-1)\ln (3 )+(3x-7)\ln (2)<(9-x)\ln (12) $$

or

$$x (\ln (3)+\ln(8)+\ln (12))<\ln (3)+\ln (2^7)+\ln (12^9)$$